# Selenium on JS getting Promise Pending

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda

I used to work with Selenium on Python, but I'm now working on a Serverless mobile app on AWS using JS.

When trying to get some text from an element it displays:

> ManagedPromise::21 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}

At the beginning my code was the following:

```
var title = driver.getTitle();
```

Next I tried:

```
var title = driver.getTitle().then(function(titulo) {
    return titulo;
});
```

That did not work either so I tried this this:

```
var title = '';
driver.getTitle().then(function(titulo) {
        title = titulo;
    });
```

All of them keep showing the same error. What should I do and how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add more context to your question? For example the scope in which you are getting the title, what function is it being called inside of?

Comment: Can you provide more details about getTitle method?

Comment: In this link you have a zip package with the info and project, that's what I'm using for it

https://medium.com/@Moatazeldebsy/ui-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-and-chrome-inside-aws-lambda-77a17ec64862